# WordPress Child CPT displaying 404 after implementing custom rewrite rules

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I need to have a very specific URL structure for this. On the website there are doctors listed, and each doctor is under website.com/practitioner/doctor-name
The doctor is a cpt. 
The tricky part is that each doctor has 3 "inner pages" and they should have the following url (unique for each doctor):
website.com/practitioner/doctor-name/inner-page-title

On top of it they will also share the same header and footer as the doctor. (so with same info in it like contact, etc.)

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'doctor_type_cpt' );
function doctor_type_cpt() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => 'Doctors',
        'singular_name'         => 'Doctor',
        'menu_name'             => 'Doctors',
        'name_admin_bar'        => 'Doctor',
        'all_items'             => 'All Doctors',
        'add_new_item'          => 'Add New Doctor',
        'add_new'               => 'New Doctor',
        'edit_item'             => 'Edit Doctor',
        'update_item'           => 'Update Doctor',
        'view_item'             => 'View Doctor',
        'view_items'            => 'View Doctors',
        'search_items'          => 'Search doctors',
        'not_found'             => 'No records available!',
        'not_found_in_trash'    => 'No records found in Trash!',
        'featured_image'        => 'Doctor Image',
        'set_featured_image'    => 'Set doctor image',
        'remove_featured_image' =>'Remove doctor image',
        'use_featured_image'    => 'Use as doctor image',
    );

$args = array(
    'label'             => 'Doctor',
    'labels'            => $labels,
    'menu_icon'         => 'dashicons-businessman', //dashicons-plus
    'description'       => 'Doctors information pages.',
    'hierarchical'          => true,
    'public'            => true,
    'menu_position'     => 20,
    'supports'          => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes', 'custom-fields' ),
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_in_menu'      => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar' => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'can_export'        => true,
    'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_doctor_metaboxes',
    'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'practitioner')
);
register_post_type( 'Doctor', $args);

$labels = array(
    'name'                  => 'Doctor Inner Pages',
    'singular_name'         => 'Doctor Inner Page',
    'menu_name'             => 'Doctor Inner Pages',
    'name_admin_bar'        => 'Doctor Inner Pages'
);
$args = array(
    'label'                 => 'Doctor Inner Pages',
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'show_in_menu'  =>  'edit.php?post_type=doctor',
    'public'                => true,
    'rewrite'           => array('slug' => '/')
);
register_post_type( 'inner_page', $args );

}
```

I then followed this [tutorial](https://1fix.io/blog/2016/02/05/parent-from-another-cpt/) to implement my desired url structure. Here is my code:

```
function my_add_meta_boxes() {
        add_meta_box( 'page-parent', 'Page Parent', 'inner_attributes_meta_box', 'inner_page', 'side', 'high' );
    }
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_add_meta_boxes' );
    function inner_attributes_meta_box( $post ) {
        $post_type_object = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );
        $pages = wp_dropdown_pages( array( 'post_type' => 'doctor', 'selected' => $post->post_parent, 'name' => 'parent_id', 'show_option_none' => __( '(no parent)' ), 'sort_column'=> 'menu_order, post_title', 'echo' => 0 ) );
        if ( ! empty( $pages ) ) {
            echo $pages;
        }
    }

function my_add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%inner_page%', '([^/]+)', 'inner_page=');
    add_permastruct('inner_page', 'practitioner/%doctor%/%inner_page%', false);
    add_rewrite_rule('^inner_page/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?','index.php?inner_page=$matches[2]','top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_add_rewrite_rules' );

function my_permalinks($permalink, $post, $leavename) {
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    if($post->post_type != 'inner_page' || empty($permalink) || in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft')))
        return $permalink;
    $parent = $post->post_parent;
    $parent_post = get_post( $parent );
    $permalink = str_replace('%doctor%', $parent_post->post_name, $permalink);
    return $permalink;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'my_permalinks', 10, 3);
```

I can create a doctor instance just fine, the urls get populated, but when I create an inner page and assign it a parent it doesn't work. (It doesn't work without a parent as well). All it does is redirect me to 404

Might it be because of a missing template? I tried flushing permalink structure. I've been at it for several hours and cannot find a solution.

EDIT: I have disabled everything regarding child parent stuff and link changes but the inner page cpt still throws 404.

Edit 2: I have disabled rewrite and it started working. Then when I enabled it back it kept working, but as soon as I change the permalink to the desired structure it throws me the 404 again.